# JQuery .on() method with multiple event handlers to one selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-1.7

Trying to figure out how to use the Jquery .on() method with a specific selector that has multiple events associated with it.  I was previously using the .live() method, but not quite sure how to accomplish the same feat with .on().  Please see my code below:

```
$("table.planning_grid td").live({
  mouseenter:function(){
     $(this).parent("tr").find("a.delete").show();
  },
  mouseleave:function(){
     $(this).parent("tr").find("a.delete").hide();        
  },
  click:function(){
    //do something else.
  }
});
```

I know I can assign the multiple events by calling:

```
 $("table.planning_grid td").on({
    mouseenter:function(){  //see above
    },
    mouseleave:function(){ //see above
    }
    click:function(){ //etc
    }
  });
```

But I believe the proper use of .on() would be like so:

```
   $("table.planning_grid").on('mouseenter','td',function(){});
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?  Or what is the best practice here?   I tried the code below, but no dice.

```
$("table.planning_grid").on('td',{
   mouseenter: function(){ /* event1 */ }, 
   mouseleave: function(){ /* event2 */ },
   click: function(){  /* event3 */ }
 });
```

Answer (score 276, accepted):

That's [the other way around](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data). You should write:

```
$("table.planning_grid").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        // Handle mouseenter...
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        // Handle mouseleave...
    },
    click: function() {
        // Handle click...
    }
}, "td");
```

Comment: Why isn't the selector `$("table.planning_grid td")` ?

Comment: @Muers, it would also work and the questioner acknowledges so, but also believes that he should bind the event on the `<table>` instead of each individual `<td>` element, which is indeed the right way to go.

Comment: There is a good reason to use the .on on the <table> and not on the <td> and it's if you dynamically add <td>s later.  
$('table td').on... will only effect the <td> that are in the table the moment you call this function.
$('table').on(... ,'td',function...)  will effect any <td> you will add to this table later.

Comment: @Raanan, indeed, and in addition every event handler one registers has a cost, albeit tiny. When you're dealing with thousands of cells, registering a single handler on the `<table>` instead of one handler per `<td>` element becomes mandatory to achieve usable performance.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi This was a hard problem to Google; but I finally found your answer. Not even the jQuery docs was clear on this. Thank you!

Comment: Agreed.  Very difficult to google this question as 'on' is such a common word and most results were related to `.bind` and `.live`.  Good answer, just what I was looking for :D @Frédéric - Your link doesn't link to a header `id` on the jquery docs page anymore.  Probably a result of updated documentation.  But I could not find this answer on that page.

Comment: Good job using the `selector` parameter.  I am now using this approach for most Form event handlers and using the selector parameter to lazy attach.

Answer (score 216):

Also, if you had multiple event handlers attached to the same selector executing the same function, you could use

```
$('table.planning_grid').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    //JS Code
});
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for

Comment: ...and then get the actual fired event type with e.type (after adding the event as a parameter, i.e. ...function(e)...

Answer (score 33):

If you want to use the same function on different events the following code block can be used

```
$('input').on('keyup blur focus', function () {
   //function block
})
```

Answer (score 15):

I learned something really useful and fundamental from [here](http://try.jquery.com/levels/4/sections/11).

**chaining** functions is very usefull in this case which works on most jQuery Functions including **on** function output too.

It works because output of most jQuery functions are the input objects sets so you can use them right away and make it shorter and smarter

```
function showPhotos() {
    $(this).find("span").slideToggle();
}

$(".photos")
    .on("mouseenter", "li", showPhotos)
    .on("mouseleave", "li", showPhotos);
```

Answer (score 9):

And you can combine same events/functions in this way:

```
$("table.planning_grid").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        // Handle mouseenter...
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        // Handle mouseleave...
    },
    'click blur paste' : function() {
        // Handle click...
    }
}, "input");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code:

```
$("textarea[id^='options_'],input[id^='options_']").on('keyup onmouseout keydown keypress blur change', 
  function() {

  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

These days this should be:

```
$(document).on({
   mouseenter: function(e) {
     // Handle mouseenter...
   },
   mouseleave: function(e) {
     // Handle mouseleave...
   },
   'click blur paste' : function(e) {
     // Handle click...
   }
}, "<selector>");
```