# jQuery bind hover to "document"

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to bind hover() to document with specified selector so that dynamically added content with matching attribute is assigned the JS function?

I've been looking at both this topic: [JQuery .on() method with multiple event handlers to one selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608145/jquery-on-method-with-multiple-event-handlers-to-one-selector) and [Is it possible to use jQuery .on and hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827095/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-on-and-hover)

and I'm currently using:

```
$('.profile-gallery-image-container').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $('.delete-image', this).show();
        $('.image-options', this).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $('.delete-image', this).hide();
        $('.image-options', this).hide();
    }
}, '.profile-gallery-image-container');
```

but without being able to pass the functionality to new content with matching selector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In delegated events approach you should bind events to one parent element of `.profile-gallery-image-container`. One possible solution is to bind it to `<body>` (or `document`) element:

```
$('body').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $('.delete-image', this).show();
        $('.image-options', this).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $('.delete-image', this).hide();
        $('.image-options', this).hide();
    }
}, '.profile-gallery-image-container');
```

Comment: Well thank you. Learned something new. Went with document and it worked.