# use $(document).on to bind multiple events to the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get used to the new proper way of doing things in jQuery but I can't figure out how to do a "live" binding that's as elegant/DRY as the original. Previously, with "live" I believe you could do this, only mentioning the element once:

```
$("#element_id").live("click",function(){
  //stuff
}).live("mouseover", function(){
  //stuff
}).live("mouseout", function(){
  //stuff
});
```

Now, with `$(document).on` it seems I would need to do this:

```
$(document).on("click","#element_id",function(){
  //stuff
}).on("mouseover","#element_id",function(){
  //stuff
}).on("mouseout","#element_id",function(){
  //stuff
});
```

This is less concise and repeats the element. Is there an obviously simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: Why would you need a delegated event for an element with a *unique identifier* (i.e. its ID) anyway?

Comment: @MattiasBuelens that was a simplified example. Specifically I'm trying to set events for table rows that are loaded dynamically via AJAX, so my actual selector I'm trying not to repeat 3 times is "#element_id tr"

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery .on() method with multiple event handlers to one selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608145/jquery-on-method-with-multiple-event-handlers-to-one-selector)

Comment: Then you should bind to `#element_id` and use `tr` as descendant selector.

Comment: @j08691 yes, this looks like it may be a duplicate of that. I looked through at least a dozen questions but didn't find that one!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$(document).on({
    click: function () {},
    mouseover: function () {},
    mouseout: function () {}
}, '#element_id');
```

Beware of using `document`; you may want to use a more specific selector.  Also I wouldn't necessarily say it's bad practice to have an ID element loaded dynamically, but it looks suspicious.

Comment: Thanks, my understanding was that if you use a specific selector, it won't apply to dynamically loaded elements, but (document) will?

Comment: @joshuahedlund: The 2nd parameter means to "delegate" the event.

Comment: @joshuahedlund As long as the dynamically loaded elements are appended within a 'static' container (e.g. a `#container` which is always in the DOM), you can use that container as binding source (instead of the top-level `document`). The selector argument then filters for events triggered by descendant elements inside that container.

Comment: @joshuahedlund in case you have any doubt, the documentation confirms this: http://api.jquery.com/on/ -- see the second usage

Answer (score 4):

I find this approach useful if your callbacks need to share code:

```
var handler = function ( event ) {

    var $target = $( event.target );

    if ( $target.is( '#element_id' ) ) }

        switch ( event.type ) {
            case 'click':
                // stuff
            break;
            case 'mouseenter':
                // stuff
            break;
            case 'mouseleve':
                // stuff
            break;
        }

    }

};

$( document ).on({
    click: handler,
    mouseenter: handler,
    mouseleave: handler,
});
```