# JQuery on click and on enter keyup, different classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Desperate late night coding before a submission.

I have two HTML objects with two separate class names that I'm looking to bind the same event with different actionlisteners.

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf" action ="">
  <input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for Sets or Cards" required>
  <button class="searchButton" type="button">Search</button>
</form>
```

I've managed to handle the button on click, and after reading the documentation for "on" I see that you can bind multiple listeners to the same class. However I can't figure out if it's possible to do the keyup as well.

```
$(".searchButton").on("click" ,function(){
```

Comment: `.on('click keyup', funciton(){`

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608145/jquery-on-method-with-multiple-event-handlers-to-one-selector

Comment: @MarkWalters: Question is reversed. I'm looking for two listeners, same event, different objects. He has multiple events, one object, same listener.

Not quite it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.searchButton, #searchInput').on('click keyup' ,function(){
```

Comment: That did the charm, thanks. Was a lot easier than I expected. I was only going to make it hit the server on return keyup, but this is much sexier as well. Many hearts

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this: jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/XAGD9/2/

```
$(document).on("click keyup",".searchButton" ,function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$(".form-wrapper").on("click keyup", ".searchButton",function(){
    // Your code here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
     $(".searchButton").bind("click keyup" ,function(){});
```