# AngularJS directives to hide zero when <input> is initially loaded to the DOM

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive, dom-events

I am trying to implement an angular directive that will hide zero of  field as soon as the `<input>` is on DOM. Basically this:

[Hide Value in input when it's zero in angular Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537792/hide-value-in-input-when-its-zero-in-angular-js)

My code look something like this :

`<input hide-zero-onload ng-model="test"></input>`

```
.directive('hideZeroOnload', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.on('input load', function() {
                console.log('loaded');
                if (this.value === '0') {
                    this.value = '-';
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

However,the console log is never printed. I also tried 'input onload', 'input init', 'input all', and 'input', with all the same result. I don't know what event keyword is emitted when the `<input>` is first added to the DOM? How can I find out?

You can check the code out http://plnkr.co/edit/TwraJlxZSd3TeSYscExq?p=preview

Comment: Just leave `test` unassigned. You can try it in your plunkr and the textbox will be empty.

Comment: @Strelok This will not work for my application. I still want to be able to display the test data on initial load if it's not zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `$formatters` for this purpose. They are designed to format the view of the model when the model is changed or initially loaded. Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/SA9xz6eQmk3t7qfRack7?p=preview

Your directive would then look something like this:

```
.directive('hideZero', [ function() {
    return {
      require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        // Specify how UI should be updated
        ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
          if (value === 0) {
            // If the value is zero, return a blank string.
            return '';
          }

          return value;
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

The `load` event may not fire for all elements. [Jquery on() load event on a single element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400152/jquery-on-load-event-on-a-single-element)