# Line jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use this plugin - [BorderAnimation Effects with jQuery CSS3 Line](http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Border-Animation-Effects-with-jQuery-CSS3-Line-js.html)

It's really works if I hover on a div, but I want that it will start when the page load and not when I'm hovering on it.
I use this code:

```
$('.simultaneous').borderSimultaneous(animationDuration, borderWidth, "onhover", backgroundColor);
```

I tried to remove `onhover`, but it doesn't works. If someone tried this plugin already and know how to do it please write it here :)

Comment: Try to add fiddle please.

Comment: fiddle of the plugin?

Comment: A fiddle of working example using this plugin.

Comment: Try `onload` or `load`, rather than `onhover`

Comment: @aPerson There is no `onload` event fired for a `div` element

Comment: According to jQuery API there is, see [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/). And [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17400326/5618881)

Answer (score 0):

'onhover' is the parameter 'activeWhen'

in the plugin, this parameter is tested with

if ( activeWhen == 'onhover' ){ // do something when hover}

else { // do something when page created }

then i say you can replace 'onhover' with any variable

you can put 'WEB R' :)

```
$('.simultaneous').borderSimultaneous(animationDuration, borderWidth, "WEB R", backgroundColor);
```

you should replace the parameters with the right values

Comment: I read and tried to do it already, but its just don't do anything.

Comment: i'm sorry, you replace the parameters with the right values ?

Comment: your div is '.simultaneous' ?