# Same selector with multiple functions/event handlers

Tags: jquery

pretty simple question here: is there a better way to write this code?

```
$('.icMenu span.menu').each(function() {
     // do something
});

$('.icMenu span.menu').click(function() {
    // do something else
});
```

I'm using the same selector twice, is there a better way I should be writing this?

Comment: For doing different stuff on different events, it is the best think to write them seperately. So I think what you have done is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608145/jquery-on-method-with-multiple-event-handlers-to-one-selector

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar: You should always avoid running the same selector multiple times if you can, so no, it is not "correct".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Options:

Use chaining as already suggested

```
$('.icMenu span.menu').each(function() {
     // do something
}).click(function() {
    // do something else
});
```

Or simply use a local variable to avoid running the jQuery selector twice:

```
var $menus = $('.icMenu span.menu');
$menus.each(function() {
     // do something
});
$menus.click(function() {
    // do something else
});
```

### Basic rule:

**The key is to always avoid running the selector more than once as that has a large overhead.**

### Delegated Events:

If your elements are ever dynamically created, you would move the `click` to a *delegated on event handler* anyway, so your question would become a non-issue (they would be the same selector, but separated in time):

```
$(document).on('click', '.icMenu span.menu', function(){
     // Do something on dynamically created elements
});
```

In a delegated event handler, the selector is only run *after* the event is caught on an ancestor (in this case `document`). The function is *then* applied to any *matching elements* that *caused the event*.

Comment: By far the most complete answer imho

Comment: @Tyblitz: Thanks. *There is a kitchen sink somewhere here I meant to include as well* :)

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `chaining`,

```
$('.icMenu span.menu').each(function() {
     // do something
}).click(function() {
    // do something else
});
```

Comment: Just wondering, why use `.each` when jQuery automatically applies the method to all elements in a class or tag selector? Or is that only the case with the `.on` method?

Comment: @Tyblitz For example if you want to manipulate anything with each elements then in that context we have to use .each()

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('.icMenu span.menu').each(function(){
    //do something
}).click(function(){
    //do something
})
```

Comment: Already covered by `Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy` (not my downvote).

Comment: Didn't see there's same answer before I post my answer (answered too slow) lol

Answer (score 0):

If your function has different names I found this solution easier

```
$('.icMenu span.menu').click(function 
    RunA() {
    }
    RunB() {
    }
);
```

This can help enable you to run Javascript normally in a JQuery file like If else Statements.  Although it may not be very practical in your case, but if you use if else in one function, it can make you run two different functions in one.
for example

```
$('.icMenu span.menu')
    .click(function 
        Run() {
            if($('.icMenu span.menu').css('display') == 'none'){
                alert("This element is hidden!")
            }
            else {
                alert("This element is visible!")
            }
        }
    )
;
```

You can replace the conditions as you need, but after all it is an example on how it is broken down (in my opinion).

Comment: I forgot entirely what alert is if i needed to add " ; " at the end to make it work.  But the whole Jquery multi function can be broken down a bit further.  The click and Each are conditions before functions, and functions themselves can be identified singular with client condition.

Comment: ignore the top part, tested it was false.  but the bottom one works.  Sadly you cannot have more than one function name with one function tag.