# How to give multiple events and handlers in .on method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, handler, mouseenter

I'm trying to move a `submenu` by using multiple handlers in `on` method.
What I want is if I moved my mouse on the one of `li` elements, event string `mouseenter` detects, then executes `function panelON` and same ways go between `mouseleave` and `function panelOFF`.

So I wrote the codes various ways but all of them didn't work and each of those have its own specific errors.

```
  target = $('#home-menu-nav ul li');
  target.on('mouseenter mouseleave', {
    convert: $('#submenu-content'),
    panelON(event) || panelOFF(event)
  })

  function panelON(event) {
    if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
      console.log('fx panelON detected')
    } else {
      return
    }
  }
```

This one prints an error `Unexpected token ||`. Seems like `||` marks cannot be used with insdie of handlers.

Next one I tried is just grouped event and handlers all of them like in this article. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608145/jquery-on-method-with-multiple-event-handlers-to-one-selector)

```
  target.on( {mouseenter: panelON(event)}, {mouseleave: panelOFF(event)} )

  function panelON(event) {
    console.log('fx panelON detected')
  }

  function panelOFF(event) {
    console.log('fx panelOFF detected')
  }
```

And this was started immediately no matter what I hovered `target` or not.

```
  target = $('#home-menu-nav ul li');
  target.on( {mouseenter: function() {
    console.log('fx panelON detected')
  }}, {mouseleave: function() {
    console.log('fx panelOFF detected')
  }} )
```

Last one. This one only prints `mouseenter`. `mouseleave` doesnt work.
Is there any ways to give and matching between events and handlers in .on method?

Comment: In your bottom two snippets, in order; the first one is incorrect because you are doing `panelOn(event)` which is trying to invoke the method.  And both of them are incorrect, because you are giving the `on()` multiple objects.  It should be `on({event1: handler, event2: handler, ...})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kekboi, welcome to StackOverflow!

Your second try,

```
target.on( {mouseenter: panelON(event)}, {mouseleave: panelOFF(event)} )
```

was quite close. Given that `()` on a function invokes the given function immediately, which is not what you intended, and as @Taplar has suggested - on takes *an* object `on(object)` - I suggest you use the following version.

```
target.on({ mouseenter: panelON, mouseleave: panelOFF });
```

```js
$(function() {
    var target = $('button.mybutton');
    
    target.on({ mouseenter: panelON, mouseleave: panelOFF });

    function panelON(event) {
        console.log('fx panelON detected')
    }

    function panelOFF(event) {
        console.log('fx panelOFF detected')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="mybutton">Hover Me Now</button>
```

Comment: @Taplar Both ways are works smoothly!! Thank you guys :>

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `on(object)` version of the bindings, you have to give it a single object, contain key/value pairs of the event:handler, as demonstrated below.

```js
$('button').on({
  mouseenter: function(){ console.log('Im In!'); }
  , mouseleave: function(){ console.log('Im Out!'); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Hover Me</button>
```