# Combining onload, resize, and window size settings

Tags: jquery

I would like to show something only if the window size is bigger than `1000px`. It should work on load, and if the window size changes.

This is my try:

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 1000) {
    alert("Hello!");
  });
}
}).resize();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work like expected. What should be changed?

Comment: You should be more clear, what is "doesn't work like expected"? What does it do instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery .on() method with multiple event handlers to one selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608145/jquery-on-method-with-multiple-event-handlers-to-one-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. Just modify the code as metioned below.

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 1000) {
    alert("Hello!");
  });  // <- remove this
}      // <- indent this (+2 spaces)
}).resize();
```

This is a good example why indentation is important. As soon as you see 2 `}` in the same column you know something isnt right - which is the case in the last 2 rows.

Working example:

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  $('#size').html('Size: ' + $(window).width());
  if ($(window).width() > 300) {
    $('#result').html('> 300');
  } else {
    $('#result').html('<= 300');
  };
}).resize();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="size"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! Can the "else" part just be deleted?

Comment: Yes, its just for demonstation purpose.

Comment: Cool, thanks! So if this part is deleted, then it just doesn't do anything if the "if" is not in use?

Comment: Exactly right. `if` only applies if the condition provided evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

To make a function run on both load and resize, you can name both load and resize in the parameter for "on".

```js
$(window).on("resize load", () => {
    alert("Hello!")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```